# how does one use the `selectionState` prop of react-native's TextInput?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm building a react-native app. I've got a `<TextInput>`, and when something occurs I wish to cause the `<TextInput>` to become focused. The only documented methods on `<TextInput>` instances are `.isFocused()` and `.clear()` -- neither seems like what I'm looking for. I obviously want `.focus()`.

I've found this iOS-only `selectedState` prop that appears to offer what I'm looking for. [The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#selectionstate) say:

> iOS **selectionState** DocumentSelectionState
>
> An instance of `DocumentSelectionState`, this is some state that is responsible for maintaining selection information for a document.
>
> Some functionality that can be performed with this instance is:
>
> - `blur()`
> - `focus()`
> - `update()`
>
> > You can reference `DocumentSelectionState` in `vendor/document/selection/DocumentSelectionState.js`

It's not clear to me how one would wield this prop, and I haven't found any examples online. The lengthy sample code posted on the doc page doesn't use it.

Can someone show me what this might look like? This is my best guess:

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    // the "DocumentSelectionState.js" file mentioned in the docs
    // lives inside react-native, so hopefully it's exported 
    DocumentSelectionState,
    TextInput,
    TouchableHighlight,
    View
} from 'react-native';
import Styles from './style';

export default class Scene extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        // get my hands on "An instance of DocumentSelectionState"
        // which I can pass to the TextInput, and whose .focus()
        // method I can call
        this.text1DSS = new DocumentSelectionState();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={Styles.CONTAINER}>


                <TextInput style={Styles.TEXT_INPUT_1}
                    // provide my own instance of DocumentSelectionState
                    // to the TextInput instead of whatever is the
                    // default source
                    selectionState={this.text1DSS}
                />


                <TouchableHighlight style={Styles.BUTTON_FOR_FOCUSING_INPUT}
                    onPress={this.onPressButton}
                >
                    <View>
                        <Text>click me to focus textinput</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
        );
    }

    onPressButton = (event) => {
        // whenever I want to, I can invoke .focus() on the DSS
        // that's linked to the TextInput
        this.text1DSS.focus();
    };

}
```

Unfortunately, that code won't run:

> undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new _reactNative.DocumentSelectionState()')

I take this to mean that react-native doesn't export a `DocumentSelectionState` member (or at least my version doesn't: 0.23, which still [documents the prop](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/textinput.html#selectionstate)).

I haven't been able to figure out how to gain access to `DocumentSelectionState` within a vanilla RN setup, so I can't really test my theory.

Has anyone out there worked with this thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I have been able to access the `.focus()` method is through the `this.refs`

Your code would look something like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './style';

export default class Scene extends Component {


    render() {
         return (
            <View style={Styles.CONTAINER}>


                <TextInput 
                     style={Styles.TEXT_INPUT_1}
                     ref={'input'}
                />


                <TouchableHighlight style={Styles.BUTTON_FOR_FOCUSING_INPUT}
                    onPress={this.onPressButton}
                >
                    <View>
                        <Text>click me to focus textinput</Text>
                    </View>
                </TouchableHighlight>

            </View>
        );
    }

    onPressButton = (event) => {
        this.refs.input.focus()
    };

}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Ah! So, presumably the other methods are also exposed on the ref. I will give it a shot tonight. If this is true, then it's bizarre to me that they would document this `DocumentSelectionState` object, since (1) it may not be possible to get your hands it, and (2) devs may not have any need for it.

Comment: I certainly found how they documented it confusing.  My guess would be that its either b/c the project is still young and changing regularly so they haven't gotten to it. Or, they want to referance `DocumentSelectionState` so developers can extend and contribute to its funtionality

Comment: Are you sure the `input.focus()` is the same method as the `DocumentSelectionState.focus()`?

Comment: @PetrPeller No, I'm not sure they are the same. Also, I wouldn't be surprised if some of the facts have changed between version 0.23 and the current one (0.56).